# Как валедировать форму ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Есть форма с переходом на другую страницу после авторизации.
Нужно что бы поля (border) меняли стиль при условиях, допустим if (e.target.value.length < 3 || e.target.value.length > 20), и также, чтобы кнопка была неактивной. Сейчас она неактивна до первого символа в полях. Пробовал сам, мало опыта, провозился весь вечер, получаю ошибки. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
type User = {
  name: string;
  password: string;
};

function MoleculesLoginForm() {
  const adminUser: User = {
    name: "admin",
    password: "admin123",
  };

  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: "" });
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const Login = (inputValue: { name: string; password: string }) => {
    console.log(inputValue);

    if (
      inputValue.name === adminUser.name &&
      inputValue.password === adminUser.password
    ) {
      setUser({
        name: inputValue.name,
      });
    } else {
      setError("Something goes wrong");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {user.name !== "" ? (
        <Redirect to={"/Chat"} />
      ) : (
        <LoginForm Login={Login} error={error} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

.

```
    interface ILoginForm {
      Login: (inputValue: { name: string; password: string }) => void;
      error: string;
    }
    
    const LoginForm: React.FC<ILoginForm> = ({ Login, error }) => {
      const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({ name: "", password: "" });
      const [formValid, setFormValid] = useState(true);
    
      const validate = ({ name, password }) => {
        const nameIsValid = name;
        const passIsValid = password;
        const isCredentialsValid = nameIsValid && passIsValid;
        if (isCredentialsValid !== formValid) setFormValid(isCredentialsValid);
      };
    
      const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        Login(inputValue);
      };
    
      const changeHandler = ({ currentTarget }: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { value, name } = currentTarget;
        setInputValue((prev) => {
          const formValues = { ...prev, [name]: value };
          validate(formValues);
          return formValues;
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div>
              <div>
                <p>User name</p>
                <input
             type="text"
             name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder="Input user name"
            onChange={changeHandler}
            value={inputValue.name}
            />
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>Password</p>
                <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        id="password"
        placeholder="Input password"
        onChange={changeHandler}
            value={inputValue.password}
      />
                {error !== "" ? (
                  <div>
                    {error}
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
              </div>
             <button
        disabled={!formValid}
        type="submit"
      >
        Log In
      </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Создавай для каждой формы булевское состояние, isValidName = true например и если значение не соответсвует условию, меня на false. Инпуту добавь стили с условием {border: isValidName ? “none” : “1px solid”}

Comment: Помоги если есть время на это. Я попробовал ещё раз. Что то где-то путаю. Там по коду почти всё готово, но не могу одно с другим связать. И через yup попробовал, также сборка ломается. У меня есть const validate, но не могу его доделать.

Answer (score 0):

в компоненте с формой создаешь состояние для каждого инпута, который надо проверять по условию.

```
const [isValidName, setIsValidName] = useState(true)
const [isValidLastName, setIsValidLastName] = useState(true)
```

Далее в функции, где ц тебя валидация формы добавляешь условия, например длина символов должна быть больше 3

```
if(value.length <= 3 && inputName === "name") {
  setIsValidName(false)
}
if(value.length <= 3 && inputName === "lastname") {
  setIsValidLastName(false)
}
```

и в самом инпуте добавляешь стиль, который говорит о недопустимом значение. Например обводим инпут красным цветом, если меньше 3 символов.

```
<input name="lastname" style={{border: isValidLastName ? "none" : "1px solid red"}}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь, но я снова что то не так делаю. Добавил то что Вы написали, и не срабатывает валидация.

Comment: Ребята, поможете?

Answer (score 0):

```
 interface ILoginForm {
      Login: (inputValue: { name: string; password: string }) => void;
      error: string;
    }

const LoginForm: React.FC<ILoginForm> = ({ Login, error }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({ name: "", password: "" });
  const [formValid, setFormValid] = useState(true);


  const [isValidName, setIsValidName] = useState(true);
  const [isValidPass, setIsValidPass] = useState(true);


  const validate = ({ name, password }) => {
    const nameIsValid = name;
    const passIsValid = password;
    const isCredentialsValid = nameIsValid && passIsValid;
    if (isCredentialsValid !== formValid) setFormValid(isCredentialsValid);


    if (inputValue.length <= 3 && nameIsValid === "name") {
      setIsValidName(false);
    }
    if (inputValue.length <= 3 && passIsValid === "password") {
      setIsValidPass(false);
    }
  };


  const submitHandler = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Login(inputValue);
  };

  const changeHandler = ({ currentTarget }: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value, name } = currentTarget;
    setInputValue((prev) => {
      const formValues = { ...prev, [name]: value };
      validate(formValues);
      return formValues;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="block__loginM">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>User name</p>
            <InputName

              style={{ border: isValidName ? "none" : "1px solid red" }}
              
              changeHandler={changeHandler}
              value={inputValue.name}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Password</p>
            <InputPass

              style={{ border: isValidPass ? "none" : "1px solid red" }}
              
              changeHandler={changeHandler}
              value={inputValue.password}
            />
          </div>
          <BtnLogin disabled={!formValid} />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).